# Rhino Mocks Use

Tags: rhino-mocks

Hello I have a class called MassRateChange and it has a method called

```
Long CreateFile(DatTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can mock this method using RhinoMocks.

The class is not static and neither is the method static.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the method is virtual and it should be as easy as:

```
var rateChange = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MassRateChange>();
rateChange.Stub(r => r.CreateFile(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now)).IgnoreArguments().Return(10);
```

This, of course, assumes the start date and end date aren't really important and you just want the method to return the value "10" during testing.

Comment: The intellisense doesnt seem to support .Stub method for rateChange

Comment: What version of Rhino.Mocks are you using?